# Does the gets() function in C automatically add a NULL character at the end of the input string?

Tags: c, arrays, gets

I am writing a simple program to convert a number(+ve,32-bit) from binary to decimal. Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    int n=0,i=0;
    char binary[33];
    gets(binary);
    for (i = 0; i < 33, binary[i] != '\0'; i++)
        n=n*2+binary[i]-'0';
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

If I remove `binary[i]!='\0'`, then it gives wrong answer due to garbage values but if I don't it gives the correct answer. My question is: does the `gets` function automatically add a '\0' (NULL) character at the end of the string or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: `gets` is deprecated.  Do not use it.

Comment: may i know why is that?

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: Using `gets()` is dangerous because it doesn't know how big the buffer is.  If you enter 32 digits (or fewer) and a newline, your code would be 'OK'.  If you enter more, or add spaces at either end, then you will run into problems.  The `gets()` function was removed from C11 (a change forecast in TC3 — Technical Corrigendum 3 — in 2007).  You should assume it causes your program to crash.  (Note that a program using `gets()` was one of the bugs that allowed the Morris Internet Worm to escape in 1988.)

Comment: Re the behaviour: the `'\0'` is added at the end of the text you entered, not at the end of the array you defined.

Comment: Note that the `for` loop condition `i < 33, binary[i] != '\0'` uses a comma operator which evaluates and discards the LHS (`i < 33`) and then produces the result of the RHS (`binary[i] != '\0'`).  If the user types 64 digits, your loop will go accessing way beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Also, the ASCII NUL (single `L`) character is different from `NULL`.  You should only use `NULL` in the context of pointers.  On some systems, it is defined as `#define NULL ((void *)0)` and using that to assign to an `char` will often (but not necessarily) trigger a compiler warning.  It depends on how fussy you set your compiler to be.

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind.

Comment: any modern C compiler will output a message about the function: `gets()`.  You should always enable the warnings then fix those warnings.  Suggest using `fgets()` (which has a different syntax, so read the MAN page)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons gets was removed in 2011. It was deprecated before that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does, writing past the end of `binary[33]` if it needs to.

Never use `gets`; automatic buffer overrun.

See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) for details.

Answer (score 2):

When `gets` was last supported (though deprecated) by the C standard, it had the following description (§ 7.19.7.7, The `gets` function):

> The gets function reads characters from the input stream pointed to by `stdin`, into the
>   array pointed to by `s`, until end-of-file is encountered or a new-line character is read.
>   Any new-line character is discarded, and a **null character is written immediately after the last character** read into the array.

This means that if the string read from `stdin` was exactly as long as, or longer than, the array pointed to by `s`, `gets` would still (try to) append the null character to the end of the string.

Even if you are on a compiler or C standard revision that supports `gets`, don't use it. `fgets` is much safer since it requires the size of the buffer being written to as a parameter, and will not write past its end. Another difference is that it will leave the newline in the buffer, unlike `gets` did.